# Flutter - удаляя элемент ListView из списка, сбрасывается состояние элемента списка под удаляемым

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, state

На первой page есть список товаров, каждый можно добавить в массив объектов (избранное), который находится выше по иерархии, оттуда просто спускается setState, и вызывается в момент когда товар добавляется, то есть обновляем состояние избранных товаров.
Весь массив этих избранных товаров передается на вторую page где в виде ListView они все по очереди отображаются. Но там есть кнопка "Удалить из избранного" которая вызывает setState переданный сверху , чтобы удалить объект из массива избранных, перерисовать ListView и показать что теперь в списке на один товар меньше.
Проблема в том, что когда я удаляю НЕ последний элемент из списка, сбрасывается состояние элемента под ним
[image: Товары в избранном]

[image: Нажал на сердечко первого тайла, удалив его из списка]
Сердечко будет светиться красным , если данный товар находится в массиве избранного, это отдельный кастомный виджет, который параметром принимает массив избранного и сам товар, и в initState проверяет содержится ли товар в массиве, если true то светится красным, если false то светится черным